# Can we save the Xcode build on Mac?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

The problem is that when we render the Mac App, it is not stored in the Applications folder. And thus have to build the project every time for using it. 
So is there any tool by which we can export the Xcode project on Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this there is an inbuilt function in Xcode.

```
Xcode > Main Menu > Product > Archive
```

After this you can export the app to your Mac.